# Mobile Center server can't configure with SSL LDAP server

Tags: microfocus-mobile-center

I follow the instructions on https://admhelp.microfocus.com/mobilecenter/en/latest/Content/configure_LDAP.htm#hp-minitoc-item-1

But unable to save the configuration successfully.

Previously, it was enable to configure with a non-SSL LDAP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to check your configuration of LDAP:
For example, you could use 3rd party ldap tools, like jxplorer login to your LDAP server, make sure the hostname, admin id and password are correct. 
Then pay attention for below fields:

Base DN: your admin ID under belong to this DN.
User ID: must use the distinguished name for the entry.
User search filter: the field you would like to use for login

If you still have issue for ldap integration. you could collect IDM logs.
Start from 2.51, IDM logs are by default enable under server/log folder (idm.log, idm-loader.log) 
Before 2.51, need to manually configure the log4j file, it is under server/jetty/idm/class/log4j.properties

If you are using SSL LDAP server. Make sure all certificate are imported to Mobile Center.